# Batch - Write output of DIR to a variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, output

I have to store the ouput of `DIR` in a variable.

This was asked before e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957309/batch-store-output-of-dir-command-into-variable-directory-listing) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663803/batch-assign-command-output-with-variables-to-variable) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307834/outputting-batch-command-to-variable).

They all provide an answer more or less similar to what I'm using right now:

```
%= Find the *.sln file and write its path to the file temp.temp =%
DIR /s/b *.sln > temp.temp

%= Read out the content of temp.temp again to a variable =%
SET /p texte=< temp.temp

%= Remove the temp.temp file =%
DEL temp.temp

%= Get only the filename without path =%
FOR %%A IN ("%texte%") DO (
    SET Name=%%~nxA
)
```

But in my case I'm sure that the ouput of `DIR /s/b *.sln` will allways be a **one-liner**. To me it looks a bit ugly to have to 
a) store the ouput in an external file and 
b) run a `FOR` loop over it though I already know it will only have one line.

**Is there any direct/simpler way to do this?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /s /b *.sln') do set "name=%%a"
```

indeed is the most efficient method (you can process the output of a command directly, no need for a temporary file).
`%name%` will contain the full qualified file name of your file (or the last of the files, if there are more than one)

Comment: `delims` is in the end the variable which I called `texte` right? And I guess I still can use `name=%%~nxA` to only get the filename?

Comment: `delims=` sets delims to "no delimiter". By default, `for /f` is processed with `tokens=1` and delimiters of space, comma, tab. If you leave it to standards, it will give you the very first word of the output only: Try (directly on command line) `for /f %a in ("hello world") do @echo %a` vs `for /f "delims=" %a in ("hello world") do @echo %a`

Comment: And yes: `? name=%%~nxA` of course is possible (Note: `for` variables are case sensitive: `%%a` is not `%%A`

Comment: Thanks a lot! This makes my script way more "uncomplicated". And its finally an answer to this question ;)

Comment: I'm using this in my own scripts, but I've found that when the filename includes an exclamation character, the variable %%a will strip those characters out, thus rendering the filename wrong. Any workaround? Oddly it works fine in the CLI.

Comment: @RamonRoyo It's neither `%%a` nor the `for`, which strips exclamation marks. It's delayed expansion. Switch it off before (`setlocal disabledelayedexpansion`)

Comment: Stephan, been looking for a solution to that for a while. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @Stephan, I also using this in my script, but when the folder name have space, it not able to find the file inside the folder. Example for the folder name E:\parent\new folder\new.txt. Any solution that might help?

Comment: @afifi: My script above processes spaces correctly. Can you show me the complete line that makes trouble?

Comment: @Stephan my code as below `set /p yy=Please enter cycle Year (YYYY) : 
set /p mm=Please enter cycle Month (MM) : 
set /p dd=Please enter cycle Date (DD) :
set /p bn=Please enter Bill No (xxxx) :

rem change to the correct directory
cd /d E:\
echo.
Echo Searching for File Cycle%yy%%mm%%dd%_%bn%
ECHO.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *%yy%%mm%%dd%_%bn%_P_*') do set "name=%%a"
IF EXIST %name% GOTO SETFILE
TIMEOUT /T 2 >nul
GOTO EOP

:SETFILE
For %%A in ("%NAME%") do (
 Set Path=%%~dpA
    Set Filename=%%~nxA
)
echo Found:
echo Path : %Path%
echo Filename : %Filename%`

Comment: @afifi: things to quote: `in ('dir /b /s "*%yy%%mm%%dd%_%bn%_P_*"') do` and `IF EXIST "%name%" GOTO`